# How to use errors codes stored in the separate module

Tags: python

In the `errors.py` module I have defined several errors such as:

```
INCORRECT_USERNAME = -2417
INCORRECT_PASSWORD = -2426
PASSWORD_EXPIRED = -2430
ACCOUNT_DISABLED = -2431
```

Now, I import this module into another Python script and check if the error code matches:

```
import errors 


def get_error_name():
    returned_code = some_function(some_argument)

    if returned_code == errors.INCORRECT_USERNAME:
        return "INCORRECT_USERNAME"
    elif returned_code == errors.INCORRECT_PASSWORD:
        return "INCORRECT_PASSWORD"
    elif returned_code == errors.PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
        return "PASSWORD_EXPIRED"
    elif returned_code == errors.ACCOUNT_DISABLED:
        return "ACCOUNT_DISABLED"
```

The resulting code appears to be too redundant or verbal. 
Is there a cleaner way to return the string value of the error message?

Comment: You can't use `return` outside of a function...

Comment: Thanks for notice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```
# errors.py
import enum

class Error(enum.IntEnum):
    INCORRECT_USERNAME = -2417
    INCORRECT_PASSWORD = -2426
    PASSWORD_EXPIRED   = -2430
    ACCOUNT_DISABLED   = -2431



# another_script.py
import errors 

def get_error_name():
    returned_code = some_function(some_argument)
    return errors.Error(returned_code).name
```

Alternatively, if you ever want to return something that isn't just the name of the error, you might consider using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
# errors.py
import collections

Error = collections.namedtuple('Error', ['name', 'msg'])
all_errors = {
    -2417: Error('INCORRECT_USERNAME', 'The provided username was incorrect'),
    -2426: Error('INCORRECT_PASSWORD', 'The provided password was incorrect'),
    -2430: Error('PASSWORD_EXPIRED',   'Your password has expired'),
    -2431: Error('ACCOUNT_DISABLED',   'Your account is disabled'),
}



# another_script.py
import errors 

def get_error_name():
    returned_code = some_function(some_argument)
    return errors.all_errors[returned_code].name

def get_error_msg():
    returned_code = some_function(some_argument)
    return errors.all_errors[returned_code].msg
```

Comment: One slight issue: the original code seems to imply that `some_function` could return something other than an expected error number, given the lack of an `else` clause. (Though that can handled by catching the `ValueError` that will be raised for an undefined return value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to do this:

**errors.py**

```py
error_dict = {
    -2417: "INCORRECT_USERNAME",
    -2427: "INCORRECT_PASSWORD",
    -2430: "PASSWORD_EXPIRED",
    -2431: "ACCOUNT_DISABLED"
}
```

```
from errors import error_dict

def get_error_name():
    returned_code = some_function(some_argument)

    # use this syntax instead of errors.error_dict[returned_code] to handle
    # invalid return code. could use a try / except KeyError also
    return error_dict.get(returned_code, "INVALID_CODE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice would be to use a dictionary, which is the best equivalent of a `switch...case` statement in other languages like C or C++:

```py
def error_handler(error_code: int) -> str:
    return {
        -2417: 'INCORRECT_USERNAME',
        -2426: 'INCORRECT_PASSWORD',
        -2430: 'PASSWORD_EXPIRED',
        -2431: 'ACCOUNT_DISABLED',
    }.get(error_code, 'DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE')
```